# Problem with renaming image with magmi image attributes processor

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magmi

I have a problem for renaming image with magmi, I use the magmi datapump API. I want an image with this name : [sku]-[imageName.jpg]

```
My image field : http://www.domain.com/data/qwerty.jpg
Image Renaming field : re::(.*)::{item.sku}-$1
Image name after import : /i/m/img52d8eaadeb5ce4.90098321.jpg
```

Someone have an idea?
Magmi : 0.7.18
Image attributes processor : 1.0.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer with the help of @dweeves :

```
re::.*/(.*)::{item.sku}-$1
```

With regex (.*) I had the beginning of the url (h t t p : / / ...) in the image name so it was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you don't need the regexp syntax for this.

1 - capturing (.*) will capture `http://xxxx` part of image field value, thus leading to invalid filename

2 - You can achieve what you need with the standard 'tag' syntax of image renaming.

```
{item.sku}-{meta.imagename}
```

Comment: I have already tested this solution, result image name : /z/f/zf709184-\_magmi.imagename\_

Comment: Edited post, looking at the code for 0.7.18, the imagename is now based on meta.xxx tags.

Comment: Now my image name is "/z/f/zf709184-", {meta.imagename} seem to be ignored.

Comment: it reminds be on a bug for meta.xxx of 0.7.18 , could you try with latest magmi git ?

Comment: I found with regex, sorry I don't have time to try the new version of magmi but it's in my todo list. Thank you very very much for your work on magmi and your useful help on my problem :)